# How to run a program with eric6

Tags: python-3.x

I have been using MATLAB for years, and I am now trying to go in to python3. The code seems similar enough, so that's fine, but I have no idea how to get an IDE to work similarly to what I am used to.

I want to type in my lines of commands, then, when I press run on the program, I want to see the results below the window where I typed my commands.

Let's say, for example, my code was:

```
a = 1+1;
print(a)
print("Hello moto")
```

and I want for the program to show me somewhere the resulting 2Hello moto or however it would print those values due to formatting. Is there a way for me to get this done in eric6? If not eric6, then are there IDEs that would be able to print like that?

Comment: This question will be better in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ; there's already your answer(s) there.

Comment: Cool. Should I delete this question since the answer is in another stack?

Comment: yes, sure......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this thread and installed PyCharm. Works how I want it to without me having to think.
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/gratis-python-ide-for-commercial-use